# understanding test and validation set usage for early stop and model selection

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I implemented an ANN (1 hidden layer of 64 units, learning rate = 0.001, epsilon = 0.001, iters = 500) with pythons OpenCV module. Train error ~ 3% and test error ~ 12%

In order to improve the accruacy/ generalisation of my NN I decided to proceed by- implementing model selection (of #hidden units and learning rate) to get an accurate value of hyperparameters and plotting learning curves to determine if more data is needed (currently have 2.5k).

Having read some sources regarding NN training and model selection, I'm very confused on the following matter -

1) In order to perform model selection, I know the following needs to be done-

```
create set possibleHiddenUnits {4, 8, 16, 32, 64}
randomly select Tr & Va sets from the total set of Tr + Va with some split e.g. 80/20
foreach ele in possibleHiddenUnits
   (*) compute weights for the NN using backpropagation and an iterative optimisation algorithm like Gradient Descent (where we provide the termination criteria in the form of number of iterations / epsilon)
    compute Validation set error using these trained weights

select the number of hidden units which min Va set error
```

Alternatively, I believe we can also use k-fold cross validation.

a. how do you decide what the number of iterations/ epsilon for GD should be?

b. does 1 iteration out of x iterations of GD (where the entire training set is used to compute the gradients of cost wrt weights through backprop) constitute an 'epoch'?

2) Sources ([whats is the difference between train, validation and test set, in neural networks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976452/whats-is-the-difference-between-train-validation-and-test-set-in-neural-networ) and [How to use k-fold cross validation in a neural network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889637/how-to-use-k-fold-cross-validation-in-a-neural-network)) mention that the training for a NN is done in the following way as it prevents over-fitting

```
for each epoch
    for each training data instance
        propagate error through the network
        adjust the weights
        calculate the accuracy over training data
    for each validation data instance
        calculate the accuracy over the validation data
    if the threshold validation accuracy is met
        exit training
    else
        continue training
```

a. I believe this method should be executed once the model selection has been done. But then how do we avoid overfitting of the model in step (*) of the model selection process above?

b. Am I right in assuming that one epoch constitues one iteration of training where weights are calculated using the entire Tr set through GD + backprop and GD involves x (>1) iters over the entire Tr set to calculate the weights ?

Also, out off 1b and 2b which is correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment but since I cant make comments yet I write it here. Have you tried other methods like l2 regularization or dropout? I dont know a lot about model selection but dropout has a very similiar effect like taking lots of models and averaging them. Normaly dropout should do the trick and you wont have problems with overfitting anymore.